Doesn't shooting a ray of light in the horizontal direction tell you whether you're moving or not?
The first postulate of the special theory of relativity states that the laws of physics are the same for all inertial frames of reference, and since things are the same whether you are stationary on the ground or on a train moving at constant speeds, the two scenarios are indistinguishable, making it impossible for an observer to determine whether he is moving or not. But consider this. you're on a rocket ship travelling at a constant speed. to verify if your rocket is on the move or not, you shoot a ray of light perpendicular to the direction of motion, and the light ray will bend downwards, or to be precise, it will draw a straight line going down instead of reaching the other end of the rocket. Through this experiment, It seems very clear that an observer will be able to know whether he or she is moving. I'd like to know what the problem is.

bending is for accelerations, not for constant velocity. You just said that your rocket is at constant speed, so there will not be any bending.

Yes, I see, but that's the reason why I mentioned that it would go down(or up) in a 'straight line'.

The observer inside will see it move to the right, not diagonal. An observor at rest outside will see it move diagonal. If you draw these situations and do some algebra its the high school level derivation of time dilation.

@DamianSowinski That is the correct answer

thanks Damian Sowinski, but I just don't know how to carry out those derivations.

@IamEinstein What part of it? If your issue is that you don't understand how to carry out the necessary calculation to see special relativity affect the system (i.e. make the light move perpendicular as seen by the rocket and diagonal as seen by an Earthbound observer, which is exactly what I stated in my answer), then you could ask "how do I carry out those derivations", not "what's the problem in my thought experiment proving special relativity".

If you point the source transverse to the direction of motion, why would the beam not be transverse?
What makes a source (e.g., an antenna) have again in a certain direction?
If the rocket is pointed in $z$ direction, then the source has an amplitude:
$$ A(x, y, z, t) = e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\equiv
e^{i\phi(\vec r, t)} $$
with:
$$ \omega = ck $$
That propagates along phase gradients:
$$ -i\vec k = \nabla \phi(\vec r) = k\hat x $$
which is perpendicular to $\hat z$, the direction of motion.

I can't say that I'm very comfortable with the equations and symbols you've just written down there, I'm afraid...

That surprises me a lot that Einstein is not comfortable with this level of math! Welcome to the site by the way

@IamEinstein yeah, so the point is, in the rest frame of the rocket, the beam shoots across, but in a moving frame, there is a phase ramp across source (consitent with the relativity of simultaneity) that causes the beam to  emitted at an angle such that it travels completely transverse w.r.t to the rocket, which is not horizontal in the frame in which the phase ramp exists.

(I'm not sure if this is what you mean)

The person in the LHS spaceship shoots a light ray to the right, the person in the RHS spaceship also shoots a light ray to the right. Both of them see the light's path as a straight line. There is no bent path.
There's nothing special about this, and you don't need light rays. You could instead imagine you throwing darts at a dart board. You aim at the bull's eye. How can you possibly do that, given that you are moving at several ten thousand kilometers per second? (The Earth is rotating, it's going round the Sun, and the Sun is going round the Milky Way) That's because from your perspective, you, the dart board, and the dart all share this common velocity. An observer who's moving relative to you would see something else.

the dark throwing astronaut doesn't not see a common velocity, he and the dart board are at rest in the rocket frame. That's the point of OP's misunderstanding: the rocket isn't moving in its frame. Just because someone else (e.g.: Houston) sees it moving doesn't create a force on the dart (or light beam).

Your question is based on a common misunderstanding. The light will go wherever you point it, but that direction is frame dependent. An easy way to see this is to suppose I shine a laser vertically in my frame. After a second the beam of light will be directly above me. Suppose you are walking past me at a metre per second in the x direction just when I shine the light. After a second in your frame, the light will be at a point around a light second above you and a metre behind you, ie the light will have taken a slightly angled path in your frame, rather than a vertical one.

Thanks, but that is exactly what I have written in my question, that the light ray would follow a slightly angled path instead of going straight.

No, the difference is that if you are the person firing the laser, it will always go where you point it, so in your rocket the light will reach the other end and it will not appear angled to you. Only to someone else, moving relative to you, is the light angled.

If your rocket is travelling vertically, and you aim a laser at a spot on the far wall of the rocket that is on the same level as you, the light will travel horizontally in your frame to hit that spot. To an outside observer, the light will also hit the same spot, but in doing so will travel slightly upwards in their frame.

In your frame, the light will hit whatever spot you aim it at- that gives you no information whatsoever about whether you are moving relative to something outside the rocket.

Oh, I guess I have misunderstood your point. But still @Marco Ocram, I am not sure if this is correct. As far as I know, the light ray won't always hit the spot you aim it at, because, as I have commented in other answers, the motion of light does not depend on its source. So switching the person with the laser won't change the velocity or the motion of light. It would only depend on who is really stationary if there ever existed an absolute speed in space.

No, your last comment is absolutely wrong!!!! You will never understand SR if you maintain that erroneous idea in your head.

The speed of light is indeed independent of the speed of its source or the speed of the observer, but its velocity is not. The direction travelled by a beam of light is frame-dependent..

I'm going to basically steal a diagram from a high school textbook that after all these decades I still have stored away in memory. It will show us how a person inside a spaceship and a person outside both see the same lightbeam which is emitted inside the spaceship. As an added bonus, it will also teach us about a very cool effect in special relativity with the fantastical name of time dilation. Let's begin!
The setup goes like this: there's a person in a rocket that has two mirrors, one on the floor, the other the ceiling. Some device in the spaceship emits light that then bounces up and down between the two mirrors. The distance between the mirrors is $L$. There's also a clock in the spaceship. Because the clock and the emitter are at rest inside the spaceship, we call the time that passes on the clock the rest time, $t_0$. The spaceship occupant measures the time it takes for the light to reflect off the bottom mirror and travel to the top mirror, where it will reflect again ad infinitum. That measurement gives $\Delta t_0=L/c$, where $c$ is the celerity, I mean speed, of light. Celerity is an old word not used much anymore meaning swiftness, and why the speed of light is denoted with a $c$. Light is swift! Anywho, I digress, the setup looks like this:
What about someone outside the ship, watching it move by? Well, this person also has a clock, but because the emitter of the light is on the spaceship and therefore not at rest with respect to this clock we call the time measured on it just regular old time, $t$. They will also see the light bounce off the bottom mirror and travel to the top mirror and bounce again etc. How much time do they measure between these two bounces? The situation looks like this:

Because the ship is moving at a speed $v$, the top mirror is in a different place when the light hits it, so the path this outside observer will see is a diagonal one. If you recall some very basic facts about right triangles, then you will have to agree that the distance travelled by the light between bounces must be $\sqrt{L^2+v^2\Delta t^2}$. Now comes the second postulate of special relativity! Everyone sees light travel at the speed of light. So, this observer also sees the light travelling at $c$ and so the amount of time measured by them is $\Delta t=\sqrt{L^2+v^2\Delta t^2}/c$.
Cool, so now we have two equations in several variables $(L,\Delta t_0,\Delta t,v,c). It would be nice if we use them to relate the time measured by the outside clock to the rest time measured by the one inside. We first square both equations to get
$$\begin{align}
\Delta t_0^2=\frac{L^2}{c²}\hspace{20pt}\Delta t^2 =\frac{L^2}{c^2}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}\Delta t^2
\end{align}$$
Plugging the left equation into the right, and doing some algebra we find
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta t^2 &=\Delta t_0^2+\frac{v^2}{c^2}\Delta t^2\\
&\Downarrow\\
\Delta t &= \gamma \Delta t_0\hspace{5pt}\text{where }\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
\end{align}
$$
We have derived the famous $\gamma$ factor, which plays a central role in special relativity. Note how it is a function of $v/c$ - the fraction of the speed of light the spaceship is travelling. In fancy places like this SE we call it $\beta=v/c$. If we plot $\gamma$ for different fractions of the speed of light we find:
You can see that $\gamma$ is always greater than or equal to $1$, so the clock outside the spaceship will always measure more time than the inside clock: an outside observer sees moving things sllllooooooooowwwwwwwwwww doooooooowwwwwn. This effect is known as time dilation. Why don't we see it in our daily lives? Well, we rarely travel anywhere close to even a millionth of the speed of light (A commercial airliner has a $v/c\approx 10^{-6})$! So we live on the very left of this plot, where $\gamma$ is so close to $1$ it might as well be equal to it.
Hopefully our little talk has helped you see the error in your thoughts. And maybe it will help other too. Good luck!

The photons have an additional velocity because they're fired out of a "moving" rocket. This makes them appear to travel to the side from the rocket's comoving reference frame; they still appear to move at exactly $c$ from the rocket's reference frame.
Say it's a bullet instead; the fired bullet has whatever velocity the gun gives it plus the velocity of the rocket, because it was fired from within the rocket. To the rocket, the bullet is moving to the side, because in the Earthbound reference frame (assuming the rocket is moving relative to Earth), the bullet's forward velocity and the rocket's forward velocity "cancel out" so that the apparent velocity of the bullet is entirely sideward. It's like two cars moving at the exact same speed on the freeway: barring looking at the ground under them, they don't see each other move relative to one another. (The "ground" in this case would be the "luminiferous aether", which was shown not to exist.)
The same applies to light beams, and anything else that the rocket could project outwards at any angle. The projectile has the total velocity of the rocket's velocity plus the velocity that the launcher imparts on it (in the reference frame in which the rocket is moving, i.e. Earthbound). It might appear to be launched at an angle from the perspective of a "stationary" observatory on Earth, but those on the rocket will see it be launched perfectly perpendicularly.

thanks for the reply~, but I'm not sure if this is true. light is a wave, or more precisely, it behaves like a wave, so its motion does not depend on the motion of the source. This was shown in the CERN laboratory in 1964 I believe. If it wasn't light, but an object, whose velocity does depend on its source, your statement would be true, but not for light as far as I know.

IamEinstein, you are correct, @controlgroup is out of control today

Light always appears to move at $c$ in any reference frame, but it still is subject to velocity addition if it's fired from a laser. My answer essentially mirrors the comment left by @DamianSowinski. Light's speed is invariant under Lorentz transformations (i.e. is independent of velocity and position) but its direction will vary by reference frame.
